# Merging excel edits from several users into a master excel workbook

Tags: python, excel, automation

I have some excel files with several workbooks in each. All of the columns are defined and I now need several users to go in and add data. Each user will make edits and send back the doc with their info added. Then someone will copy and paste all the changes into the master workbooks. Very time consuming process and I was wondering if I can make this quicker with python. My idea is this load the master and the edited spreadsheet into a dataframe and loop through each cell in both do the following.

1. If a cell in the master is blank but has data in the edited file, then copy the info in that cell to the master.
2. If the cell in the master has data but it is not the same as the edited file then overwrite the cell in the master with that info.
3. If the cell in the master has the exact same info as the edited file then do nothing to the cell.
4. If the cell in the master and the edited file are both blank do nothing to the cell.

Is this a possible solution or is my logic way off and there is an easier to do this? These excel docs are huge so the copy paste method takes a very long time and I would like to speed up this process for my team. So basically I want to add each users edits into the master without overwriting any other users edits in the process. Thanks in advance for your help with this.

Answer (score 1):

This is certainly possible within Python but if you are looking for the continued ease of use for your team, building it as a macro in VBA may be better. User could go into the submitted document, click a button on the ribbon, and it would work through the process with a relatively nice UI. While Python may be nominally faster, you could be asking your team to interact with a terminal interface (using Py2exe or pyinstaller) or you may need to install Python on their workstations (to use xlwings, for example).

I'm not sure of the exact layout of your data, but here's an example of how the VBA process could work:

1. User opens edited file and clicks macro button on ribbon
2. Macro asks for user to select Master Document (assuming Master Document is not always the same)
3. Based on Sequence/ID column (usually column A), insert a helper column to the right of the data that validates whether their entered data is the same or different than the Master Document (could use CONCAT() to create one cell of data for comparison if there is multiple columns they're editing)
4. For items that are different (would include both where they're blank or changed), copy those respective ranges over

There are many ways to break down the logic into executable code, so that is just an example of one possibility. Python is a powerful language but for automating Excel data entry or administrative tasks like this request, VBA is often the easiest way forward.

Comment: I'm really not an excel person so python will be the easiest route for me. VBA sounds more complicated. As far as my users I can build a web interface for them to input the master file and the edited version or just run it myself for now.